# Hover effect performance issues

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

i have a div with a background image and inside that div i have a component called Hero. I wanna apply a simple hover effect on a div with a className newBigButton, but the transition is so laggy but when i remove the background image the transition works fine.. here's the code :

```
      <div
        className="hero-section"
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          display: "flex",
          backgroundImage: bg ? `url(${bg})` : "",
          backgroundPosition: " 60% center",
        }}
      >
        <Hero />
      </div>
```

part of Hero component code :

```
  <div style={{marginTop: "15vh"}} className="d-flex w-100 flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div style={{gap: "20vh"}} className="d-flex ">
      <div className={styles.newBigButton}>BESOIN IMMÉDIAT</div>

      <div className={styles.newBigButton}>PROJET À VENIR</div>
    </div>

    <div style={{marginTop: "8vh"}} className={styles.newBlueButton}>Demander une démo</div>
  </div>
```

The CSS :

```
.newBigButton {
  color: #2863a9;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #2863a9;
  padding: 3.5vh 2vh;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.newBigButton:hover{
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  background-color: #2863a9;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thats probably because the image gets loaded once you hover it, it not preloaded

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress They aren't loading a background image on hover.

Answer (score 0):

###### The laggy transition effect you're experiencing when you have a background image in your hero-section div is likely due to the rendering performance of the browser, especially if the background image is large or the component structure is complex.

Large images can take some time to load and render, which can affect the smoothness of CSS transitions.

###### You might want to try optimize the background image

Ensure that your background image is properly optimized for the web. You can use image editing software to reduce its size and resolution while maintaining acceptable quality. Smaller image files will load faster and improve performance.

Comment: Yep, i tried a small image and it works fine and i tried other browsers it works fine too